# Concept of Hybrid Filtering- Image Processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, hybrid

I am thinking to work on hybrid filters for speckle noise. What is a hybrid filter? I will explain my understanding of hybrid filters below.I am unsure whether my understanding is correct. Please correct me if I am wrong and also help me to learn the other methods to construct a hybrid filter.

For example, I take mean and median filter.

1. First, I take an image and apply mean filter. Next, the output of mean filter(filtered image) is then given to the input of median filter. Can we call this as a hybrid filtering ?
2. First, I take an original image 'I' and apply mean filter to get an output image 'X'. Next, I take the same original image 'I' and apply median filter to get an output image 'Y'. Now, I add X and Y. Finally, the filtered image `Z= imadd(X,Y)`. Can we call this as hybrid filtering?

Give an idea about hybrid filtering and what are the other ways of constructing hybrid filters.

In some matlab codes, they use `im2double` .I understand that it converts the intensity image I to double precision but what is the need for this conversion? Is it must? How it affects the program?

Again, in some matlab codes, they use `uint8`, `uint3`, `uint16` along with `imshow`. I understand that `uint8` converts the elements of an array into unsigned 8-bit (1-byte) integers. My question is how I will know when to use `uint8`,or  `uint3`, or `uint16`. OR when to use `uint8`,or  `uint3`, or `uint16`?

Answer (score 1):

Hybrid filter are those that are a combination of two or more filters. Your understanding of them is correct. For eg I can create an hybrid filter using median filter and Weiner Filter etc.. The point is your purpose of using them.

Since you are removing speckle noise you can try adaptive median filter.

And for your question on using uint3,uint8 etc.. see this

http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/creating_plots/working-with-8-bit-and-16-bit-images.html

Comment: Is there any other ways to implement hybrid filters than the methods I have stated above?

Comment: I do not think so that you add the outputs of images but I believe that you need to pass on the output of one filter as an input of another filter.                                                    For eg. Input Image--->Mean Filter--->Median Filter-->Output Image